# suggest me a good RAID card each for SATA and SAS for Ubuntu 10.04, which will get recognized easily?

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have an IBM x3550 server. The RAID controller that comes along is an LSI Megaraid and does not get recognized by Ubuntu boot up CD. I am looking for an alternate RAID card, which works for 10.04 PCI Express

Answer (score 1):

How about trying the latest daily build before replacing the card? The bug [[Bug #546091]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/546091) looks to have been resolved in 10.04.1.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/lucid/daily/current/

Answer (score 0):

How about [THIS](http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/products/controllers/hardware/sas/performance/sas-5805/) Adaptec 5805; does SAS/SATA, PCI-e and appears to be fine for 10.04.